# Perl - Using Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI with encoded URL's

Tags: perl, swagger, openapi, mojolicious

I am in the process of creating restful APIs using the OpenAPI(swagger) v2  Specification using Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI for my Mojolicious App.

I have to create a GET endpoint where a URL will be passed as query parameter.
This particular URL is a random URL which may be encoded (even punnycoded).
Sometime it contains special character also (e.g [http://example.com/4v3iI6HO/Ù](http://example.com/4v3iI6HO/%C3%99)„Ø¹Ø¨+-+Ù).

My OpenAPI Specification json is -

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "MyApp API"
    },
    "schemes": ["https"],
    "basePath": "/api",
    "host": "myapp.com",
    "paths": {
        "/uri_lookup": {
            "get": {
                "x-mojo-name": "get_urls_details",
                "x-mojo-to": "API::Urls#get_urls_details",
                "operationId": "get_urls_details",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "query",
                        "name": "url",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Url to search"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Url Details",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "object"
                        }
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "description": "Unexpected error",
                        "schema": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my Controller class I an checking the valid url, querying the DB and returning the response.

```
sub get_urls_details {
    my ($self) = @_;

    $self->openapi->valid_input or return;

    # Checking it avalid url (starting with http/https or ftp)
    $self->_validate_url( $self->param("url") );

    if ( not $self->validation->validator->has_error ) {
        my $input = $self->validation->validator->output;
        my $url = $input->{'url'};

        # Till here everything is working fine for a normal url.
        # But if a url contain special character,
        # I am not able to see proper value here
        my $uri_encoder = URI::Encode->new( { double_encode => 1, encode_reserved => 0 } );
        $url = $uri_encoder->encode($url);
        $self->app->log->info($url);
        # Will be looking into DB here
    }
    else {
        $self->respond_to(
            any => {
                status => 400,
                json   => { message => 'Bad request. Invalid url' }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

I have those url's in DB in percentage encoding form (%). In the api request I will be getting the url in random encoding form(Chinese encoding, punnycoded etc). I have to encode these url to there percentage encoding and look into DB.
I have tried to do it throgh URL::Encode but I am not gettign 100% correct percentage encoding(it all convert '+' to percentage encoding which I don't want). I am quite frusted from last couple of days with these encoded url and I am not sure how to cope with it.

My question are -

1. What is the correct way to handed these type of URl's in the backend side.
   Is the module I am using is correct ? Is there something wrong with my approach?
2. I found 'allowReserved' parameter in open api doc (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/) which I think can be used to handle such url's but when I used it my OpenAPI Specification json and updated the parameter section like-

> ```
> "parameters": [
>                     {
>                         "in": "query",
>                         "name": "url",
>                         "required": true,
>                         "type": "string",
>                         "description": "Url to search",
>                         "allowReserved": true
>                     }
>                 ],
> ```

I started getting errors-

```
Can't load application from file "/home/Developmentmyapp": Invalid JSON specification HASH(0x41e3fe0):
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/0/oneOf/0 Properties not allowed: allowReserved, type.
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/0/oneOf/1/oneOf/0 Properties not allowed: allowReserved.
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/0/oneOf/1/oneOf/1 Properties not allowed: allowReserved.
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/0/oneOf/1/oneOf/2 Properties not allowed: allowReserved.
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/0/oneOf/1/oneOf/3 Properties not allowed: allowReserved.
- /paths/~1uri_lookup/get/parameters/0: /oneOf/1 Properties not allowed: allowReserved, description, in, name, required, type. at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/JSON/Validator.pm line 164.
        JSON::Validator::load_and_validate_schema(JSON::Validator::OpenAPI::Mojolicious=HASH(0x3eee5b8), Mojo::Home=SCALAR(0x3e7b200), HASH(0x41ea790)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/JSON/Validator/OpenAPI/Mojolicious.pm line 39
```

I am not sure why this error is coming. Is this particular param is not supported in plugin ?

Version I am using -

Perl - 5.22

Mojolicious-  8.24

JSON::Validator - 3.14

Mojolicious::Plugin::OpenAPI - 2.16

**API request -** [http://localhost:3000/api/uri_lookup?url=hxxp://tets.com/xeroxep3290_all/TtQoy_B0/4v3iI6HO/Ù](http://localhost:3000/api/uri_lookup?url=hxxp://tets.com/xeroxep3290_all/TtQoy_B0/4v3iI6HO/%C3%99)„Ø¹Ø¨Ø©+Ø§Ù„Ø§Ù…Ù…+-+Ù…Ø§ÙŠÙ„Ø²+ÙƒÙˆØ¨Ù„Ø§Ù†Ø¯.exe

**Url I am getting in backend during request-** hxxp://test.com/xeroxep3290_all/TtQoy_B0/4v3iI6HO/%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%98%C2%A8%C3%98%C2%A9%20%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%A6%C3%99%E2%80%A6%20-%20%C3%99%E2%80%A6%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C5%A0%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%B2%20%C3%99%C6%92%C3%99%CB%86%C3%98%C2%A8%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%A0%C3%98%C2%AF.exe"

**Url in DB -** hxxp://test.com/xeroxep3290_all/TtQoy_B0/4v3iI6HO/%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%B9%C3%98%C2%A8%C3%98%C2%A9+%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%A6%C3%99%E2%80%A6+-+%C3%99%E2%80%A6%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%C5%A0%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%B2+%C3%99%C6%92%C3%99%CB%86%C3%98%C2%A8%C3%99%E2%80%9E%C3%98%C2%A7%C3%99%E2%80%A0%C3%98%C2%AF.exe

I am expecting the URL in back end and DB should match . Ideally I should have the same URL as in database.

Comment: Looking at the API request, I see that the substring `©+` has been encoded as `%C2%A9%20` and in the DB it is `%C2%A9+`. I see two issues with this: 1) `+` should not be `%20`, but `%2B`, according to [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), and 2) The DB seems not to encode reserved characters, so `+` is not encoded in the DB.